# Python Flask-Restful - Object has not endpoint

Tags: python, flask

Good Evening,

I am having some serious troubles getting flask-restful to work for me, It should be very simple and has been in the past but I am trying to load my libraries in a different format and I keep running into this error.

I am very new to python so I am sure I am making some simple mistake.

I am basing my structure and loading dynamic off this skeleton https://github.com/imwilsonxu/fbone

The basics are this
In my extensions file I have this defined

```
from flask.ext import restful
api= restful.Api()
```

Then within my app.py file am doing this

```
app = Flask(app_name, instance_path=INSTANCE_FOLDER_PATH, instance_relative_config=True)
configure_app(app, config)
configure_blueprints(app, blueprints)
configure_extensions(app)


def configure_extensions(app):
  # Flask-restful
  api.init_app(app)
```

Then finally within a given blue print I am importing the api and trying there hello world example

```
from sandbox.extensions import api

class HelloWorld(restful.Resource):
def get(self):
    return {'hello': 'world'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')
```

This is the error I am getting.

AttributeError: 'Api' object has no attribute 'endpoints'

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dont think you have posted all of your code... where do you reference endpoints?

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are trying to add the flask-restful resources to the api object before it has reference to a valid instance of the Flask app.

One way to get around this would be to wrap all your add_resource calls in a separate function and then call this function after the app and the extensions have been initialized.

In your blueprint -

```
from sandbox.extensions import api

class HelloWorld(restful.Resource):
def get(self):
    return {'hello': 'world'}

def add_resources_to_helloworld():
    """ add all resources for helloworld blueprint """
    api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')
```

In app.py

```
def configure_extensions(app):
  # initialize api object with Flask app
  api.init_app(app)

  # add all resources for helloworld blueprint
  add_resources_to_helloworld()
```

This will make sure the resources are added to your app only after the api object has reference to an initialized Flask app ie. after init_app(app) is called.